# Online tutorial requested: functional derivatives

Tags: reference-request, calculus-of-variations, quantum-field-theory

I am taking a course on Quantum Field Theory where we work alot with the functional derivative.

Does anyone know of a good, free online PDF tutorial with some examples?

Cheers!

Comment: It may be helpful to learn a little functional analysis. In this case the relevant topic is the Gateaux and Frechet derivatives on locally convex topological vector spaces. A lot of the stuff physicists do will make more sense if you learn the math for real instead of in their hand-waving manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at following introductions.

Unfortunately I don't know how good they describe functional derivative, figure it out by yourself.

[Quantum Field Theory. Mark Srednicki](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf)

[Quantum Field Theory. Frank Wilczek](http://web.mit.edu/physics/people/faculty/docs/wilczek_quantum_field_theory.pdf)

[Introduction to Quantum Field Theory. Arthur Jaﬀe](http://www.arthurjaffe.com/Assets/pdf/IntroQFT.pdf)

[An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory. Mrinal Dasgupta](http://www.stfc.ac.uk/ppd/resources/pdf/dasgupta_08_intro_to_qft.pdf)

[An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory. Hartmut Wittig](http://wwwkph.kph.uni-mainz.de/T//members/wittig/talks_lecture/ral.pdf)

The next list should be more useful I assume

[Funcational Methods in Quantum Field Theory. Alex Nelson](http://notebk.googlecode.com/files/functionalQFT.pdf)

[Quantum Field Theory II.Dr. Matthias R. Gaberdiel, Dr. Aude Gehrmann-De Ridder](http://www.itp.phys.ethz.ch/education/lectures_fs11/qft2/script)

[Advanced Quantum Field Theory.Prof. Claudio Scrucca](http://itp.epfl.ch/webdav/site/itp/users/181759/public/aqft.pdf)

Hopefully It will be helpfull!

Comment: FMiQFT by Nelson looks promising. Thanks!